# Get Google space members for all spaces under google workspace

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, google-workspace, google-chat

I'm working on Google workspace analysis and got stuck on one analysis, where i want to fetch Google space members for all spaces under google workspace. I have tried to use the GAM command for this but its giving me below error.

**Command**- gam print chatmembers space spaces/spaceID

**Error**- ERROR: 403: This Chat app is not a member of this space - 403

Kindly suggest a way to get members for spaces.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with [GAM-advanced](https://github.com/taers232c/GAMADV-XTD3):

Use this command:

```
gam all users print chatspaces todrive
```

Then, in the sheet that is made, filter out any doubles by using the [unique-function.](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/10522653?hl=en)

Note: Depending on the size of your domain, this might take a couple of minutes...

Comment: I have already tried this and getting error - ERROR: chatspaces is not a valid argument for "gam <users> print"

Comment: Then you are probably using 'classic' GAM and not GAM Advanced. You could also be using an older version of GAM, that hasn't yet have support for Chat Spaces.
Update your GAM-advanced install with this command: 

bash <(curl -s -S -L https://raw.githubusercontent.com/taers232c/GAMADV-XTD3/master/src/gam-install.sh) -l

Then, check the serviceaccount:
gam user user@mydomain check serviceaccount
And follow the steps to finish the setup.

Comment: GAM is updated to GAM Adv already still its giving error in cloud shell

Comment: If you updated and checked your serviceaccount and permissions in Google Admin, then I'm afraid I can't help you. Maybe you can post your question in the GAM Public Chat? https://git.io/gam-chat